# How can I add aditional conditions in Django Login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

I want my login function to classify If `user` is an `one-to-one field` in `Alumni` or `Personel` table.

If `user` is related to `Alumni` table, log the user in and redirect to profile page.

If `user` is related to `Personel` table, log the user in and redirect to another page.

`model.py`

```
class Alumni(models.Model):
    Alumni_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    User_id = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pic')
    LinkedIn = models.CharField(max_length=256 , null=True , blank=True)
    Line = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True  , blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50 , null=True  , blank=True)
    Province = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Sub_District = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Postal_code = models.IntegerField()
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True , blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.IntegerField( null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return ("Alumni id:%s" %(self.User_id))
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse('Alumni_detail', args=[str(self.Alumni_id)])

class Personel(models.Model):
    Personel_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    User_id = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length=50 , null=True  , blank=True)
```

`view.py`

```
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the instance being available in the table like so:

```
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request.user)

            # Check here
            try:
               is_alumni = Alumni.objects.get(User_Id=user)
               return redirect('/profile')
            except:
               return redirect('/other-page')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})
```

Note that this assumes that each user is either related to `Alumni` or `Personel`. Also make sure to use the common naming convention for your model fields being lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a type field in user object.

yourapp/models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

USER_TYPE = (
    (1, 'Alumni'),
    (2, 'Personel'),
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=USER_TYPE,
        default=1,
    )
```

and add this in your settings.py

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '{YOUR_APP_NAME}.{YOUR_USER_MODEL}'
```

then, each time a user log in you can check for the type.

yourapp/views.py

```py
def login(request) :
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request.user)

            # Check here
            if user.user_type == 1 :
                return redirect('alumni')
            elif user.user_type == 2 :
                return redirect('personel')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})
```